# Can't open Ionic Framework compiled project in Android Studio

Tags: android, ionic-framework, compiler-errors, build-tools

I'm currently working on `Ionic Framework` based Android App. I've complete setup of Android Studio & Android SDK.

- Android Studio 2.2.2
- Android SDK Tools 25.2.2
- Android SDK Platfrom Tools 25.0.0
- Android SDK Build Tools 25.0.0
- Android SDK Platform 24 rev. 2
- Android SDK Platform 23 rev. 3
- Android Support Repository 39
- Google Repository 37

The `ionic build android` & `ionic emulate android` commands works fine. but, When I'm attempting to open build project in `Android Studio`, it throws the following error.

```html
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'E:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\25.0.0\aapt.exe''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I can't figure out what's going wrong. Any suggestions or help are welcomed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which OS are you using? might be problem with permissions.

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1.

Comment: one thing I would suggest just try executing another sample android project with Android studio and if it works then the thing you could try is just delete .gradle and build folder of your Ionic project and then try to import this.

Answer (score 0):

check `E:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\25.0.0`.for `aapt.exe`some times it occur due to missed options or ircorrect  directory

Comment: I've checked, aapt.exe is there at exact place. Ionic framework compiles it successfully. So, Aapt.exe itself is not problem. Maybe something goes wrong with Android Studio